# Can't boot from USB stick

Tags: linux, windows, boot, bios, dell-inspiron

I have an Dell Inspirion 5590 with Windows 11
BIOS version 1.17.0

I want to replace Windows 11 with Pop OS (supports UEFI) for this laptop

I already use various usb bootable creators like: ventoy, rufus, lili... But my laptop does not recognize the usb sticks as bootable

I think that is some bios configuration, because its possible to see the drive on boot options, but its just not recognized as bootable

My secure boot is disabled

My bios config
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

EDIT 2

The BIOS detect USB stick on boot options, but I can't boot from that stick

EDIT 3

Like ChanganAuto said I set to never the boot path security and recreate my usb bootable stick  and I discovery something interesting, my efi folder has boot folder and some .efi files inside, I can see that on windows explorer. But on Boot Options when I open that folder to get .efi to boot this folder is empty. That means something?

EDIT 4

Now I use Win32DiskImager to create Bootable USB disk from Pop OS and I could boot the USB stick, but when the USB is booted I receive the following error

error: invalid magic number
error: you need to load kernel first

Comment: In order to answer your question, I must two things about Pop OS, does it support Secure Boot and UEFI mode? Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Does the BIOS detect the USB stick and lists it in the Boot Options menu? Press F8-12 during boot since I'm not sure which one Dell uses.

Comment: @Ramhound Pop!_OS is Ubuntu based so the answer is yes to both questions.

Comment: Instead of using "alternative" methods I'd suggest using a simple DD based tool that guarantees a 1:1 copy of the ISO. Something like Balena Etcher is available for all major OS families. Of course you should verify (checksum) the ISO before burning regardless of the tool. And I'd suggest setting the UEFI Boot path security to "Never" (1st screenshot)

Comment: Are you attempting to replace Windows 11 with Pop OS or dual boot both systems?  If Pop OS does support Secure Boot shouldn't it be enabled?

Comment: @Ramhound I want to replace. Do you receive notification when I update my answer? And enable secure boot does not resolve, I already tried that.

Comment: I don't typically subscribe to questions.

Comment: I release a new update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could format my laptop

First of all, none of my usb sticks was recognized by my BIOS.

When I've tried with my father's usb stick the BIOS recognize files at first time, then I just move Pop OS files to inside the usb stick and boot againg and install Pop OS nicely.

I think that is all about the usb stick properties, I will attach some print screens

**My first 2 usb sticks that doesn't work**
[image: doesn't work]
[image: doesn't work]

**My father's usb stick that works**
[image: works]